# ASP.NET Core Docker image deploys/runs successfully, but gets 404

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .Net 6 ASP.NET Web API project, built into a Windows docker image and running in an Azure App Service (as a docker container). The logs show everything is correct.  However, when I attempt to visit the swagger page of this Azure Web App (using the "default domain"), I get a 404.  Example addresses I've tried:

- https://dockerbasedsite.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html ==> returns 404.
- https://dockerbasedsite.azurewebsites.net ==> returns 404.

Why is it unreachable?

A little more context...my app successfully deploys as a Windows docker image to Docker Hub.  My Azure App Service fetches the image from Docker Hub. Likewise, Visual Studio also can launch the same docker image in Windows Docker desktop...and allows me to inspect the swagger page exposed by the docker container.

Thus everything looks "just right", and yet I have the 404 when served from the Azure App Service.

Here is the dockerfile I am using:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Alrium.WebAPI/Alrium.WebAPI.csproj", "Alrium.WebAPI/"]
COPY ["Alrium.Data/Alrium.Data.csproj", "Alrium.Data/"]
COPY ["Alrium.Services/Alrium.Services.csproj", "Alrium.Services/"]
COPY ["Alrium.StyleMapper/Alrium.StyleMapper.csproj", "Alrium.StyleMapper/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Alrium.WebAPI/Alrium.WebAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Alrium.WebAPI"
RUN dotnet build "Alrium.WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Alrium.WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Alrium.WebAPI.dll"]
```

This dockerfile was created for me by Visual Studio.  The only thing I changed was the build image...I changed it to Server Core (it defaults to Server Nano).  I made that change because of a build problem that Microsoft said is circumvented by using Server Core.

Any ideas?

Comment: See following : https://forums.docker.com/t/404-page-not-found-after-docker-compose-start-on-windows-10/115092

Comment: Any updates? If you need further help, pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

According your description, you can fix the issue by annotating the Isdevelopment conditions. The code should like below.

```
        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

        /// ====>comment this condition app.Environment.IsDevelopment())<===========
        //if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        //{
        //    app.UseSwagger();
        //    app.UseSwaggerUI();
        //}

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Api v1");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthorization();


        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
```